# Does the bitcoin testnet3 network support Segwit and OP_CSV?

Tags: testnet, segregated-witness, checksequenceverify

As far as I know, Segregated Witness and OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY are the last features needed to be able to fully implement a trustless bi-directional payment channel, from start to finish. (Technically you don't need OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY, it just makes channels a lot better)

Does testnet3 support those features?

If not, is there another public development chain which has those features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, `testnet3` supports SegWit as of block 834624.
2. Yes, `testnet3` supports both OP_CSV and OP_CLTV.

You might also be interested to know that there is a `segnet` test network on another port number. See https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1453392.0 for more details.

Comment: Segwit activated on testnet3 in block 834624 (may 13th), and segnet was deprecated after that...

Comment: @Pieter -- If we run Core wallet v.0.13.0-rc1 on Testnet now, does it mean the transactions we make are segwit transactions? And how can I find out they're segwit transactions? Thank you.

Comment: You need to use `addwitnessaddress <normaladdress>` to make the wallet produce a witness P2SH address. If you're paid through that address, and then spend those coins, then yes, it will be a segwit transaction.